# How to convert numeric time to HH:MM

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a time field which displays as the following:
9:50:03 is 95003
14:53:44 is 145344

So when it's a single digit hour, the value is only 5 characters vs double digit hour is 6 characters.

I need to convert 95003 to 9:50  and 145344 to to 14:53 following this formula for any time.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this in any language I would parse the data by 2 digits and add a : to each part. I would need to know what language to help you though. Or if it does not matter please emphasize.

This is very general without seeing your formula, but this is how I would go by doing it.

EDIT:

```
NumberVar dur := Sum ({@elapsed});
NumberVar hrs;
NumberVar min;
NumberVar sec;
StringVar hhmmss;

hrs := Truncate(Truncate(dur/60)/60);
min := Remainder(Truncate(dur/60),60);
sec :=Remainder(dur,60);

hhmmss :=totext(hrs,"00")+":"+totext(min,"00")+":"+totext(sec,"00");
```

Second Try

```
datediff("s",datetime(date({table.occdate}),{@enroutetimetotime}),datetime(date({table.inservicedate}),{@inservicetimetotime}))
```

OR - Probably your best shot

```
numbervar ntt := {YourTable.NumberField};

stringvar nttx := totext(ntt,"000000");
time(val(left(nttx,2)),val(mid(nttx,3,2)),val(right(nttx,2)))
```

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for the quick response. This would be for a Crystal Report formula so the data displays correct. Tbh, not sure if its a specific language used for it..?

Comment: When I put that formula in it just shows as 56790:56:32 regardless of the value in the field.

Comment: Couldnt an easier way be to trim the last 2 characters and then put in an :

Comment: Updated my response. Try that

Comment: Hi Jay I appreciate your quick response. I used the 3rd formula and it's working, but I was hoping to change a couple things. First, it's converting it to 12 hour time, and I need it as 24 hour time. It is also showing AM & PM which I don't need. So its currently converting 145344 to 2:53:44 PM and I need it to show as 14:53 and ignoring the seconds. And I was hoping if the value is 0, then it will show N/A.

Comment: Sorry hit send too quick on my above response :)

Comment: I believe in crystal reports you can just change it from 12 hour to military as long as it returns as a time field. If not maybe totext({?TimeInput},"HH:mm:ss") for the output may help

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure how to incorporate that into the formula you provided.